# Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Y" with NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I'm creating a **people reducer**...

However, we know that requests may very well fail and that is why I inserted in `getInitialState()` some properties such as `data`, `error` and `loading`.

The `data` is an `object` of type `People` to be able to enter the values ​​of the specific person.

The `error` is an `object` of type `RequestError` if an error occurs in the request.

Finally, `loading` is the loading of requests.

The error that occurs is that it says that the `RequestError` interface is not signed in the `People` interface, which is obvious, because I am using the state as a base.

[image]

**How do I do this implementation?**

**ERROR:**

```
var error: RequestError
Argument of type 'RequestError' is not assignable to parameter of type 'People'.
  Type 'RequestError' is missing the following properties from type 'People': id, isMain, avatar, messagests(2345)
```

**ACTIONS:**

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { RequestError } from '@shared/interfaces/request.interface';
import { People } from '@shared/interfaces/people.interface';

export const GET = createAction('[GET: USER/API] Get a people');

export const CREATE = createAction('[POST: USER/API] Create a new people', props<{ data: People }>());
export const CREATE_SUCCESS = createAction('[POST: USER/API] Successfully created person', props<{ data: People }>());
export const CREATE_FAIL = createAction('[POST: USER/API] Failed to create a new person', props<{ error: RequestError }>());

export const UPDATE = createAction('[PUT: USER/API] Update a people', props<{ id: string; changes: Partial<People> }>());
export const UPDATE_SUCCESS = createAction('[PUT: USER/API] Person updated with success', props<{ id: string; changes: Partial<People> }>());
export const UPDATE_FAIL = createAction('[PUT: USER/API] Person update failed', props<{ error: RequestError }>());
```

**REDUCER:**

```
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { People } from '@shared/interfaces/people.interface';
import * as fromPeopleAction from './people.actions';

export interface State extends EntityState<People> {}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<People> = createEntityAdapter<People>({
    selectId: (people: People) => people.id,
});

const INIT_STATE: State = adapter.getInitialState({
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
});

const peopleReducer = createReducer(
    INIT_STATE,
    on(fromPeopleAction.CREATE, (state: State, { data }) => adapter.addOne(data, { ...state, loading: true })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.CREATE_SUCCESS, (state: State, { data }) => adapter.addOne(data, { ...state, loading: false })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.CREATE_FAIL, (state: State, { error }) => adapter.addOne(error, { ...state, loading: false }))
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
    return peopleReducer(state, action);
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at Redux DevTools and check if in a successful `People` creation action, `data` remains null? If you can share the state Tree would be good also.

Comment: Inserted the chart!

Answer (score 0):

As your chart shows, `data` property from `State` remains null, even when your **CREATE** action is successful, which means that the issue is with your action's props. Since your `EntityAdapter` is of type `People`, when you call the function `adapter.addOne()`, it is expecting params from type `People`. The way you modeled your State, `data`, `error` and `loading` are `People`'s properties, which means that when you want to add or update any property, you need to wrap it inside of People class.

In summary you would have to change your CREATE_FAIL action's props to something similar as:

```
props<{ people: { error: RequestError } }>()
```

Or when you call `adapter.addOne()`, wrap it.

In case you already have the people state created on store and want to add an error, you can call `adapter.updateOne()` instead of `addOne()`.